# Using a user defined function in SQL returning a table based on 2 parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, user-defined-functions

I've defined a UDF that splits a certain string into multiple substrings based on a type I provide.

```
ALTER FUNCTION Split (@MainString varchar(100), @Type char)
RETURNS @PartsTable TABLE
(
    C1      varchar(10) NULL,
    C2      varchar(10) NULL,
    C3      varchar(50) NULL,
    C4      varchar(10) NULL,
    C5      varchar(50) NULL
)
AS
BEGIN       
    declare @pC1    as varchar(10)  
    declare @pC2    as varchar(10)
    declare @pC3    as varchar(50)
    declare @pC4    as varchar(10)
    declare @pC5    as varchar(50)

    -- cut string into pieces   
    /*
    do some work
    */

    -- fill return table 
    INSERT @PartsTable (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5)
           select @pC1, @pC2, @pC3, @pC4, @pC5
    RETURN
END
```

It provides me with the correct resultset:

```
C1      C2     C3     C4     C5
--------------------------------------
M.C.    NULL   Test   NULL   NULL

(1 row(s) affected)
```

When I call it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.[Split]('Test M.C.', 'X')
```

How can I incorporate this in a normal SQL query, I was trying something like follows for a table;

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable X, dbo.Split(X.ColumnString, X.Type)
```

But that doesn't work. It provides me with the following error:

> Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.SplitsKlantNaam_T1", or the name is ambiguous.

Does anyone know how I should call this UDF?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CROSS APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in this situation, e.g.

```
select *
    from MyTable X cross apply dbo.Split(X.ColumnString, X.Type);
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d221/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Never heard of the cross apply method. Superstuff :)

Answer (score 1):

this happend because function returns is a table so you should treat function as table

```
select * from  [dbo].[Split] ('karim pentest')

[dbo].[Split] : is the name of my function
```